# Inaccurate median display in boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot, median

In the `boxplot` below, the median display in the 'no cancer' group is inaccurate. It should be 19.15, but it looks much lower.

What could have caused the inaccurate display?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some data so we can attempt to reproduce your "error"?

Comment: Are you sure it's not the _mean_ that's 19.15?

Comment: You are correct. I looked at the wrong 'm' word. Thank you for looking at it :-)